# How to get default value of a field in an abstract class

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Suppose I have a class like this:

```dart
abstract class Foo {
  String name bar = 'bar';
}
```

Using mirror, can we get the value of `bar` ?

Comment: Depends. Do you have an instance of this class?

Comment: This is an interesting question but tricky as he wants the default value. If a constructor overwrites the default value you can't get it from an instance either.

Comment: True, didn't think about the constructor here. Also realised I wrote "instance" instead of "subclass". An instance would be pretty worthless anyway.

Comment: No, it doesn't have subclass. The reason I'm asking this is because when I browse through the tests code of [dado](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dado), the author is passing an abstract class as its constructor argument and able to get the default value of one of its field. I might be wrong about that, nonetheless I still want to know if it can.

Comment: does it not just new up an instance and ask for the value of the property from the instance after its been new'd up?

Comment: @BudiSutrisno which file and line of the source are you refering to?

Comment: I remember a recent discussio about instantiating an abstract class related to dado. This is probably the use case it is needed for. This worked but was removed and the discussion was about reitroducing this feature. There shoud be an issue in the Dart bugtracker too AFAIR.

Comment: Two references to my recent comment
https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/sBOGTD5btaM, https://github.com/dart-lang/dado/issues/16

Answer (score 1):

General answers:

- You can use `super.field` if you're extending a class and want to access its fields/getters.
- If you're reflecting on a class declaration, you can't currently introspect on any bodies, including method bodies, or initializers. You would have to use the analyzer or dart2js.
- Dado is... interesting in how it works. It tries to instantiate the abstract class, and doesn't actually work anymore.

Since you were looking at Dado, let me explain more how it works, even though it's not a general answer to this question.

First, the approach with Dado was and is pretty experimental. I was trying to use the language features to require a declarative definition of modules so that authors couldn't write modules that didn't work with code-generation. There have been some changes in Dart and mirrors that make this approach less workable, or at least makes it require more boilerplate, so I'm rethinking the whole thing. Take any technique you find there with a gain or two of salt :)

For anyone else who hasn't looked at a sample or the code, in Dado you declare an abstract class for a module definition. A field with a value is declaring a fixed singleton value, similar to how a more traditional DI container might have you write `bind(Foo).toValue(new Foo())`.

The way I (used to) get the value is by instantiating the abstract class via mirrors, and simply then simply read the field. dart:mirrors changed to disallow instantiating abstract classes, so this no longer works. This is unfortunate, because other types of bindings were declared with abstract methods, and those cause warnings in non-abstract classes.